# RStudio opens up with full environmet

Tags: r, rstudio

when I try to open RStudio, it opens with this environment and I can't open any files because it looks like RStudio is loading this large matrices.

I just want to open RStudio and start with a clean environment and no .rmd files on it

[image]

I have aleady deleted all .RData Files and .Rhistory files, uninstalled and installed both R and RStuido, and still, it opens up with all .rmd files and this large matrices on the environment

Comment: Look into your default working directory, see `Tools >> Global Options >> General`, maybe there are the files and delete them. You can also look into `Tools >> Project Options >> General` and uncheck some stuff.

Comment: man, I can't open Global Options, when I click there, it does not open anything, it is like my RStudio crashes right away

Comment: You could potentially find out what's in the matrix and then run a query throughout your harddrive and figure out where the source is. You're most likely regenerating .Rdata. What operating system do you use?

Comment: @user171558 I'm using Win10. It looks like is exactly this, because those files are big, they have 30M elements, and when I saved the wokspace, it looks like is trying to regenerate that and is consuming too much RAM. Do you know how to run that query?

Comment: I wish I knew for Windows. I'd do a simple find command from the root directory on linux. When you reinstall, do you install in the same directory?

Comment: @user171558 i've already reinstalled in other directory, but the same happens, it loads up those large matrices, i cant clean the environment and cant open a new .rmd file or global options

Comment: I guess your issue is solved! Make sure to click on the click on the check mark next to the answer so the question is flagged as solved.

Answer (score 2):

Ah, yeah, sop go to tools > global options > R General

There you'll see options to restore data on startup. Uncheck those.

[image]

If the matrices are so large that it's causing you to run out of RAM, you may need to delete the rproject file (and associated things like .rproj.user. .rhistory, .Rdata, .ruserdata --you may need to enable show hidden files to do that). Or just make a new project and start fresh (copy over the files and data from the broken project directory).

Comment: yeah, the poblem is that i cant open global options, it crashes right away, and it loads that environment and I cant clean it

Comment: Okay, so totally uninstall rstudio. Delete the directory it was in too so you get rid of all the config files that can linger after a soft uninstall. 

Otherwise this may help you:
https://support.rstudio.com/hc/en-us/articles/200534577-Resetting-RStudio-Desktop-s-State

Then, like I said, In the directory of the project it's opening, delete everything but the code and raw data (you may need to enable showing hidden files). 
Reboot, and reinstall rstudio.

Comment: YES, that worked like charm. I changed that config file name and it opened up a fresh r session. Thanks a lot

Comment: No problem! If you could do me a favor and mark it as solved that'd be great (for internet points :p)